# Passing a value from a C# from to a VB form

Tags: c#, vb.net, forms

I need some advice on how to get a VB.NET form to return a value from a C# form.

Unfortunately converting the VB project to C# would simply take to long.

Both are completely separate projects they are independent of each other and not in the same solution.

Basically the C# app has 3 parameters nRoll,nPitch,nYaw they are declared as integers. I would like my VB project to be able to get these 3 values so they can be used in the VB form.

Is it possible to do this with separate projects or would I have to look at doing something more complex like adding the VB project into the C# solution and passing the parameters like you would with normal forms, would this work ?

Everything I have found on the web seems to tell me that this is not possible without compiling one of the projects into a DLL and referencing it to be able to parse the values between the two projects. However I don't particularly want to do this as I may end up finding I have wasted time if it does not work.

The other method I have thought of is silly and inefficient but I could simply write the 3 values from the C# project to a text document and then parse the values in VB to use them provided this is possible without getting a file in use error.

So if anyone has knowledge in doing this could you please guide me through the procedure since it's only 3 values I need I am looking for the most simplest method. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks
~Callum

Comment: This is called Inter Process Communication

Comment: Search here for `[c#] interprocess communication` (with the brackets).

Comment: @meda Ahh Thank you I knew there was something like that I just did know how to word it. I have used this in the past for sending data from an Xbox 360 controller to another form I can't believe I forgot about Window Messaging, so I should be able to get this to work.

Comment: Your subject is somewhat misleading - you want to pass values between C# and VB _processes_, not _forms_. And I can mention that what I use for this is something called "named pipes", but that is rather old-fashioned, there are more modern techniques.